# How to show page title in blog post of wordpress site

Tags: wp-title

I want to show the page title in single post page of wordpress theme. I tried to use `<?php echo get_the_title() ?>` but it returns the post title, not the page title.

basically I want to show my page title, in this case "Blog" below my header area in single.php file. how do I make it?

Comment: in wordpress a page is a post too! please give more details about your question

Comment: comment deleted! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to show the page title in single post page

What do you mean by "page title of a single post page" The title of a single post page will be the same as the current post being displayed.

The retrieve and display the page title of a single post page, use the native function [`single_post_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_post_title). Just add it where you need to display the title

> ...I want to show my page title, in this case "Blog" below my header area in single.php file

Blog **cannot** be the page title, except when your post's name is blog. If the name "Blog" is something else or derived from any other source, you'll need to reveal that source then

If my answer doesn't answer your question, please file an edit and properly explain what you want.

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation. yes I understand it properly now. :)

Comment: Glad it worked. Removed my comments as well. Enjoy :-)